Android Studio change button stroke
I set my button stroke color, but it takes the primary color instead of the one I set. How can I set my selection to what I want instead of the primary. I am using this xml on EditText also it takes correctly the color. I guess Button has default settings and the one of them is color:primary or something
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="30dip"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/dark_onBackground"/>
    <solid android:color="?attr/customSolidColor"/>
</shape>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.LightMode" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="BackgroundPrimary">@color/background</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/primaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/onPrimary</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/secondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/onSecondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/onSecondary</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/orange</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="customStrokeColor">@color/onBackground</item>
        <item name="customSolidColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>



    <style name="Theme.LightMode.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.ChatGPTDeneme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.ChatGPTDeneme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Widget.NavigationView.Custom" parent="Widget.Design.NavigationView">
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/primaryContainer</item>
        <item name="itemIconTint">@color/primaryContainer</item>
    </style>




</resources>


I add funtion to change it and it change according to DarkMode boolean
    private void setButtonStyle(Button button, boolean isDarkMode) {
        button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), isDarkMode ? R.drawable.rounded_corner_null_dark: R.drawable.rounded_corner_null));
        int strokeColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), isDarkMode ? R.color.dark_onBackground : R.color.primary);
        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(strokeColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }

